# Reset count of buttons so it starts from Button 1 again after all Buttons are deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I have inserted the following three `buttons` into my Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

*I am using a German Excel version: Schaltfläche = Button*

As you can see the `buttons` are counted by `1,2,3` and each additional `button` will get the next higher count number.

Now, I run the following VBA to delete all `buttons`:

```
Sub Delete_Buttons()
Sheet1.Select
Sheet1.Buttons.Delete
End Sub
```

After I run this VBA I insert the `buttons` again:

[image]

As you can see the `buttons` are counted starting from `3`.

How can I reset the count of the buttons and make the count starting from `1` again?

Comment: Can you delete the worksheet? New worksheet or closing/reopenning the workbook will do. Also you could edit their name upon inserting them.

Comment: Try to use shapes.count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is:

1. Run the VBA to delete all buttons:

   ```
   Sub Delete_Buttons()
   Sheet1.Select
   Sheet1.Buttons.Delete
   End Sub
   ```
2. Save the file and close it.
3. Re-open the file and then insert the buttons again. 
   *(Now it starts counting from Button 1 again)*

Answer (score 0):

or you could use a sub that "orders" the buttons text by their `Left` property

this example uses a `SortedList` object

```
Sub Rename_Buttons()        
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

        Dim btn As Button
        For Each btn In Sheet1.Buttons
            .Add btn.Left, btn
        Next

        Dim j As Long
        For j = 0 To .Count - 1
            .GetValueList()(j).Text = "Button" & j + 1
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Michi, any feedback?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The only issue I see with this solution is that in the background Excel still keeps the counting so after I run your VBA the text of the buttons is changed to 1,2,3 but once I insert a fourth button it will have number 7 instead of number 4. I wonder if there is a way to reset this counting in the background. Similar to the way of reseting the internal sheets name here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336555/reset-internal-sheet-name-back-to-an-ascending-order

Comment: just re-run `Rename_Buttons`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
Sub create_new()

    Dim counter As Long, MaxValue As Long, i As Long
    Dim btn As Button, btnNew As Button
    Dim FullBtnName As String

    counter = 3
    MaxValue = 0
    'You could change sheet name
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Loop all butons in the sheet
        For Each btn In .Buttons
            'Split the name to get its number
            FullBtnName = btn.Name

            If CInt(Split(FullBtnName, " ")(1)) > MaxValue Then
                'Get the max number
                MaxValue = CInt(Split(FullBtnName, " ")(1))
            End If

        Next btn
        'Loop 3 times to create 3 shhets
        For i = 1 To 3

            Set btnNew = .Buttons.Add(.Range("A" & i + 5).Left, .Range("A" & i + 5).Top, .Range("A" & i + 5).Width, .Range("A" & i + 5).Height)
            'Change button name & caption
            With btnNew
                .Caption = "Button " & MaxValue + i
                .Name = "Button" & MaxValue + i
            End With

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```