# Reset internal sheet name back to an ascending order

Tags: excel, vba

I opened an Excel spreadsheet consisting of 5 `sheets` which looks in the VBA window like this:

---

[image]

*I am using a German Excel version so **Tabelle = Sheet***

---

As you can see the count of the `Sheets` is not correct since `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` were deleted during the development process and two new Sheets (`Sheet6` and `Sheet7`) were inserted.

Now, I am wondering if there is a way to reset `Sheet6` and `Sheet7` so they get assigned internal sheet number `2` and `3` to it?

Comment: You are looking for sheets's `CodeNames` which can't be changed during runtime, but you can just do so manually in the VBE. Just change the values underneath  the VBE project explorer (select a sheet) in the properties window.

Comment: @JvdV, seems like [you actually can change codenames during Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472829/change-sheet-code-name)

Comment: Whoa - learn something new every day...

Comment: That's new to me @Displayname. I'll have to look into that. It's funny cause official documentation says [otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the sheet in the VBA window, then press <kbd>F4</kbd> if the properties page isn't already open.

There, you can see it has a `(Name)` and a `Name` property - you can change them both to whatever you want (at design time).

[image]

Comment: Is there also something similar for buttons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335249/reset-count-of-buttons-so-it-starts-from-button-1-again-after-all-buttons-are-de